# slick carousel not working for some large image(bolb url image path) in windows 7 Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, windows-7, cross-platform, slick.js

i have made the simple image preview demo by using the slick carousel.

In this demo i have display the image by setting the blob path as image src by java script for large images. but for some large images it not display the images in windows 7 Firefox.
while in other system like Linux, mac it is display properly for all browser.

i have not found where the issue is.

this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Album Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css"/>

  <style>

    .imagePreviewDiv{
        height: 170px;
        margin-top:5px;
          table-layout:fixed;
    }
    .displayBorder{
        border-style: solid;
    }
     #content{
      height: 160px;
    }
    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
    }
    .slick-slide {
      transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .slick-active {
      opacity: 1;
      margin: 5px auto !important;
    }
    .slick-current {
      opacity: 1;
    }
   .slider {
     width: 100%;
   }
   .canvas-container .canvasClass.lower-canvas, .canvas-container, .canvas-container .upper-canvas.canvasClass{margin:6px 0 6px;}
   .slick-initialized .slick-slide{border-right: 2px solid #fff; height: 150px;background: #ccc; display: flex;  align-items: center;}
   .slick-initialized .slick-slide img{margin: 0 auto;max-width: 100%;  max-height: 100%;}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row displayBorder imagePreviewDiv">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1" ><input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-11"  id="uploadedImageDiv">
            <div id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var currentPreviewImage = 1;
// funcation used for initialization of the silk library for image preview 
function loadFunctionSilk()
{ 
  $("#content").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        draggable:false,
      });
}


       loadFunctionSilk();

        $(function () {
            $("#fileupload").change(function () {

                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

                    var dvPreview = $("#content");
                    var totalFile = $($(this)[0].files).length;

                    // allowed file extention
              var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png','gif'];
              var fileUploadedExtention = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

                    $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                        var file = $(this);

                    if ($.inArray(fileUploadedExtention, fileExtension) != -1) {            
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                var img = $("<img />");

                                // make the object url bolb url
                                var bolburl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file[0]);

                                img.attr("src", bolburl);

                                img.attr("class", "imagemagin");

                                // set up the currentPreviewImage as id 
                                img.attr("id", currentPreviewImage);

                                //to release the object URL since it's no longer needed once the image has been loaded.
                                img.onload = function() {
                                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(bolburl);
                                }

                                var spantag =  document.createElement('span');
                                img.appendTo(spantag);

                                $('#content').slick('slickAdd',spantag);

                                currentPreviewImage = currentPreviewImage +1;

                                // free the memory no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked  
                                if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) 
                                {
                                  // only do for firfox only for solve the issue of data image in url while dragging  
                                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(bolburl);
                                }
                            }

                            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file[0]);

                        } else {

                            alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                            dvPreview.html("");
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```